# Getting data if one value is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue with the code below and my issue is the following:

I need to be able to select the `shop_shipping_rule_region_code` if the `country_iso` is `NULL` but I also need to get the `$country_iso` data as well if present

**What I am after:**

The Final Result will have:

```
Overnight UPS
NZ Snail Mail
Whole World (in this example)
```

**DB:**

```
`shop_shipping_rules` (`shop_shipping_rule_id`, `shop_shipping_rule_country_iso`, `shop_shipping_rule_region_code`, `shop_shipping_rule_name`, 
    `shop_shipping_rule_type_single`, `shop_shipping_rule_item_single`, `shop_shipping_rule_type_multi`, 
    `shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple`,`shop_shipping_rule_created`, `shop_shipping_rule_modified`, `website_id`)
     VALUES
    (41, 'NZ', 'ALL', 'Overnight UPS', 'single', 2.00, 'multi', 4.00, '2013-11-05 02:30:19', '2013-11-05 03:00:27', 64),
    (44, 'NZ', NULL, 'NZ Snail Mail', 'single', 25.00, 'multi', 35.00, '2013-11-14 03:57:06', NULL, 64),
    (45, NULL, 'ALL', 'Whole World', 'single', 90.00, 'multi', 150.00, '2013-11-14 05:05:53', NULL, 64),
    (46, NULL, 'EU', 'EU Ship', 'single', 28.00, 'multi', 35.00, '2013-11-15 01:04:01', NULL, 64);
```

Comment: The top half of the question seems to be talking about selection and references a variable, the bottom half is an insert. Are you asking for help with a `SELECT` statement? If so, can you show us what you currently have?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I am wanting to write a select statement I have also removed the insert as this was just to show the db table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($country_iso))
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM shop_shipping_rules WHERE country_iso IS NULL OR country_iso = '$country_iso' ";
else
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM shop_shipping_rules WHERE country_iso IS NULL";
```

Comment: `$country_iso = "'; DROP TABLE \`shop_shipping_rules\` --";`